# Run NodeJS application without environment variable

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables, nohup

I have a node application that I run on a Linux Server (CentOS 6.5) by setting my environment with a bash script

```
env_nodejs.sh

#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/opt/nodejs/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin
export PATH
```

So that I can

```
# . ./env_nodejs.sh
# node /var/www/html/application/app.js
```

That all works fine but if I do the following in a separate script

```
run_app.sh

#!/bin/bash

$COMMAND=/opt/nodejs/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node
$SITE=/var/www/html/application/app.js

nohup $COMMAND $SITE > /tmp/nodeapp.log &
```

This runs the node server and app but with errors that seem to be related to npm

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "control/users" in views directory "/views"
```

I have a feeling this is because the environment is not set but is there a way to run it correctly without the environment or to pass additional parameters for the npm location?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's trying to find the files in `"/views"` which is a top level directory in your file system.

If that is the case then it's not `PATH` but `PWD` that's in fault here.

Make sure that when you define where to look for the views in your app, instead of saying `'views'` or `'./views'` you use `path.join(__dirname, 'views')` instead.

You first need to require `path` with: `var path = require(path);`

Of course this is just my guess as you didn't include any part of your source code that you have problem with.

Comment: the source code works it just doesn't work when the environment isn't set